# Examples of Sanborn map WMS?

Tags: web-mapping, web-service, history, copyright

I'm wondering if anyone has heard of or come across any examples of scanned and georeferenced Sanborn Fire Insurance maps being served as a WMS.  I know there are copyright issues, so presumably only for maps before 1922.  I'm curious about the possibility of doing this myself...  Thanks!

Comment: Not WMS, but NYC library recently announced that they were putting their maps up: http://www.nypl.org/blog/2014/03/28/open-access-maps/ Fire maps are a major part of that: http://digitalcollections.nypl.org/search/index?filters[rootCollection_rootCollectionUUID_s][]=Atlases+of+New+York+city.||de1dcfb0-c5f6-012f-1dfc-58d385a7bc34&keywords=atlases+of+new+york+city&sort=keyDate_st+asc#/?scroll=0

Comment: Nice resource.  I'll file that link away for later.  Thanks!

Comment: As you've had no responses confirming presence of any WMS, perhaps you would consider deleting the question, or post your own answer with your own WMS...

Comment: I could, and have been planning to add an answer once the project is officially released, but why delete the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Been waiting years to do this, but **finally** able to answer my own question here, given the recent release of the project I was working on when I originally asked the question.

In the Cane River Heritage Inventory & Map, an installation of Arches (an open source heritage inventory platform), I have included a couple examples of Sanborn layers on the interactive map.

http://crhim.canerivernha.org

To view them, go to the map, and find these layers in the Historic Maps panel.

I did some image-editing in GIMP, georeferenced each sheet in ArcMap, and they are served as WMS through GeoServer.